# c integer division not returning correct quotient

Tags: c, math, math.h

my code (in the C language) is this:

```
avg = round((r + g + b) / 3);

r = avg;
g = avg;
b = avg;
```

It should do the grayscale image effect. There are no syntax errors, but apparently avg, when calculated as shown above with values `r` as 27, and both `g` and `b` as 28, avg finds it to be 27. I know it is 27.66666... and when rounded that is 28. if you can either-or/both explain to me why this happens with `round()`, and/or give me a solution, it is really appreciated.

Comment: What types are `r`, `g`, and `b`?

Comment: Also, that can't be your code, or it wouldn't even compile. You have an extra `)`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica that wasnt my exact code. but i'm %100 certain that the only problem was in the calculation, so i wrote it in pseudo-ish code. also, im not sure what r, g, and b are because i'm using a bitmap library to acess the image, so maybe int, long, or float.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that `r`, `g`, and `b` have integer types, the expression `(r + g + b) / 3` performs integer division because all operands have integer type.  This means that any fractional part of the division gets truncated.

Change the expression to this:

```
(r + g + b) / 3.0
```

The constant `3.0` has type `double`, so this will perform floating point division.  Then rounding the result of this expression will give you the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your code won't compile due to the missing `(` before `r`.
2. You didn't provide the primitive data types, so I assume `int`.
3. Dividing the sum by 3 performs an integer division, so 27 is correct.
4. What you want is `round((r + g + b) / 3.0)`, which will implicitly cast `(r + g + b)` to `double`.

Comment: my code could compile, i just wrote it wrong here. you see, i didn't exactly copy-paste my code because it was a bit confusing. see for yourself:    `gscale = round((image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtBlue) / 3.0);` but thanks!